# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, server, networking, sockets

Server Program:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 class Server{
   public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        String str = (String)dis.readUTF();
        System.out.println("Message : "+str);
        ss.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Client Program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class client{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",8080);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeUTF("Hello friend ");
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
        s.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
 }
```

When I execute this program. I got an error like this "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" But before it works fine. Please anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Perhaps two instances of the same process running at the same time, trying to bind to the same port twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're restarting the server side of your program multiple times, there may be sockets in TIME_WAIT hanging around that prevent you from listening on port 8080 again.

You need to set the enable the reuse option (socket option SO_REUSEADDR) as follows:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
ss.setReuseAddress(true);
ss.bind(new InetSockAddress(8080));
```